# System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on xamarin.android to develop `searchableView`.
But i get error:

```
Caused by: md52ce486a14f4bcd95899665e9d932190b.JavaProxyThrowable: 
System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination 
type.
at Main.Droid.Activities.MainActivity.OnCreateOptionsMenu    
(Android.Views.IMenu) [0x0009a]
```

Thanks

Comment: We can't do anything without source code. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve